# jQuery Plugin/JavaScript: Set body-class with actual URL

Tags: javascript, jquery

I know there are JavaScripts or jQuery plugins which set some body classes (e.g. something like that `<body class="ff3.5 ff win gecko some-awesome-icons-article-with-100-icons">`)
I don't know how that is called...?
Do you know what I mean and have you a link/name of it?
The path to the article set as css-body-class is more important for me than for example the browser or OS.

Comment: Can you offer some more info as to why? Setting an url as className seems a bit overboard. There's bound to be a better way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a JavaScript solution: http://snipt.net/mountainash/javascript-adds-classes-to-body-based-on-url/

Answer (score 2):

I think you're asking for code that will extract the "filename" portion of the url path, and set that as a class name on the body element.

If so, then here's the basic idea:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    var parts = window.location.pathname.split('/');

    var basename = "default-no-basename";
    if( parts && parts.length ) {
        var idx = parts.length-1;
        if( parts[idx] == '' && parts.length > 1 ) {
            --idx;
        }
        basename = parts[idx];
    }
    //alert("basename: "+basename);
    $(body).addClass( basename );
});
```

That code simply extracts the portion of the page url following the final slash, and writes it into the `class` attribute of the body tag.  If the url path is a "directory" (ie. it ends with a slash), then it'll use the trailing directory name instead.  If the url path is just '/', then it'll default to adding the classname `'default-no-basename'`.

**Important:** The above code *does not* do anything to ensure that the classname is compliant with the allowed characters in css classnames.  So if your url was something like:  `http://example.com/abc/my-cool-page(with stuff).html`, then you're going to have problems, because the css class will be set to `"my-cool-page(with stuff).html"`.

You would therefore want to either ensure that this is never being called on a page that has special chars (like `(`, `)`, `.`, and the [space] character in the above example).  Or you'll want to add some checking in to that logic to strip out disallowed chars.

good luck.

Answer (score 1):

If I've understood your query, you need to add a class to certain tag. Using jquery this is how it can be done.

```
$('body').addClass('anyClass');
```

Comment: Thanks but I know how to set/add a class with jQuery ;-)! But that I don't need...